# How to access/test android action bar using appium?

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation

I'm trying to write automate test to test elements of Android Action Bar (like Menu Icon, search icon, ... option). I want to perform basic action like clicking on these icons, then selecting sub items from option menu items, or typing text after selecting Search icon in action bar.

Is there any way to access these elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll tell you whatever I know having worked a little bit with Appium. I don't think there's any direct distinction which will tell you that it's an action bar. There are some things you can do :

1. You can examine the page source by using driver.getPageSource(), and search whether an action bar exists in the screen (This would only work if the app uses a standard action bar, in which case it would contain 'android.support.v7.app.ActionBar' element. This is just one part of your problem, and this won't work with apps which have a custom action bar (which is very common among apps).
2. So once you've discovered the app contains an action bar, you need to get access elements of that action bar. Again, I don't think there's any standard API in Appium, which tells you that this is the search button or the menu button. They are just plain imageviews for appium, and all you can get is either the resource-id of those image views or the content description or other attributes like clickable, enabled etc.

   ```
   String resourceId = element.getAttribute("resourceId");
   ```

   `String contentDesc = element.getAttribute("name");`

You can then match the contentDesc against some pre-defined patterns (such as 'More Options' for menu options view, and 'Search' for search view.) Once you match these, you can assume that you've found your element and can click it using web element's click method.
You can also use keycode 82 and if the app supports option menu using the hard menu key, it will open.

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.MENU);
```

Again the same goes for the option menu sub items (you can either fetch all the web elements, as far as Android is concerned, it can be buttons, textviews, imageviews, edittext etc. but I don't think there's any way to filter out those which are the sub items in the options menu from the total list). Another approach is maybe comparing the earlier page source with the updated page source to observe the changes after the options menu  view has been clicked. The same method can be used when the search button has been clicked, and you can examine the page source for 'SearchView' to be sure that there exists a searchview in the action bar where you can type your query text.

As I said earlier, there may be a better way to accomplish this task, and I would surely appreciate if someone posts a better answer which helps all.

Comment: Thanks gaurav jain, it works. All we need to find elements either by id, resource id, description. In my case for opening Menu "Open" is desc. Thanks again

Comment: Which driver class are you using that you can perform `driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.MENU);`?

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks My bad, it has been replaced now, you can use pressKeyCode instead of sendKeyEvent to perform the desired operation. I'll update the answer.

Comment: And for which class is the `pressKeyCode` used?

Comment: It's a method of AppiumDriver class but you can use with AndroidDriver too since it simply extends the former.

Comment: I see it only in `AndroidDriver` class. Is it true or do I need to update my dependency?

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks You are right. Maybe it's due to me being using a different version of Appium. It no longer exists in AppiumDriver.